# Should the cursor property be set in a rule with or without the :hover pseudo-class?

Tags: css, css-selectors, semantics

Say you, or I, have coded an HTML element...

```
<a id='hydrogen' href='#'>H</a>
```

...and some `:hover` CSS...

```
#hydrogen:hover {
  background:red;
}
```

...and now we want to put a fancy hand cursor when hovering.  There's two options for this:

apply to stateless element:

```
#hydrogen { 
  cursor:pointer;
}
```

or, apply to :hover state.

```
#hydrogen:hover { 
  color:red;
  cursor:pointer;
}
```

My question: is there *any reason(s)* why one way is decisively better than the other?

...or is it tomato, tomato?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Compatibility: IE6 and below only recognize the `:hover` pseudo class on `a` elements.

Answer (score 3):

They are both the same, provided you *always* want the `pointer` there, reguardless of hovering.

The `:hover` pseudo class [will inherit `cursor: pointer` from its non hovered state](http://jsfiddle.net/alexdickson/z9nmr/).

I would prefer to put it on the normal selector, rather than `:hover`.

Comment: The non-hovered state is not represented by the lack of a `:hover` pseudo-class, but explicitly by `:not(:hover)`. This is why the question calls it "stateless", and is also why the style will be applied.

Answer (score 0):

Both ways are equally good. However i would put it on the id itself as `:hover` does not work on ie6 or below if element is not an anchor. If you do not care about older versions of IE. Then both ways are correct.