# Applying cursor:pointer with button vs button:hover

Tags: css, mouse-cursor

I was wondering whether using `button {cursor: pointer}` has some downsides or reasons not to do it instead of `button:hover {cursor: pointer}`?

I feel really dirty typing `button` instead of `button:hover`, so I want to make sure I'm not doing anything bad.

Comment: Possibly relevant: [CSS better to change cursor on hover, or on stateless?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5348660/css-better-to-change-cursor-on-hover-or-on-stateless)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no real difference between the two and no problems that could come to mind. If you load up the HTML below, you can see that even if there's a hover effect used the cursor change to a pointer exactly the same as if it didn't use a transition (which is the only effect I could imagine it having). If you prefer to use `:hover` then you can; however it is good practice to minimise the code you write in anything.

```
  <html>

<head>
    <title>Pointer</title>
</head>

<body>

    <button class="pointer">Pointer</button>
    <button class="hoverPointer">Hover Pointer</button>
</body>

<style>
    .pointer {
        cursor: pointer;
    }

    .hoverPointer:hover {
        -webkit-transition: 2s;
        transition: 2s;
        cursor: pointer;
        background-color: aqua;
    }

</style>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks! But as @Showdev pointed out, it only differs in ie6. Thanks for example though